# wp_nav_menu action/filter help

Tags: menus, filters

Maybe an odd question, I have a site that makes heavy use of nav menus. I'm looking to improve my site's performance, and since the menus hardly ever change, I wrote some PHP to spit them out into static files. What I can't figure out though, is if there is a way for me to hook into `wp_nav_menu` so that I can get the `theme_location` name (so that I can determine which static file to output) and then prevent `wp_nav_menu` from hitting the database and putting together the menu.

If I add in this filter:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter');
function my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter($args = array()) {
    //$args['walker'] = new my_walker_class();
    return array();//$args;
}
```

and then either return `false` or an `empty array` I still seem to get a nav, or an error generated in my custom walker. So is there no way to prevent a nav from being generated and from wp hitting the db trying to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once you supply a custom walker there is no need to return `false` or `array()`. Simply return `$args` and WP is going to delegate the menu generation to your custom walker.

Comment: Yes, but what I would like to do is to actually abort the nav process, and serve up a static version that I have saved on disk. I just can't seem to find a hook to abort, and then return some static html.

Comment: I think you can achieve that from within your walker and simply return the static html. Your walker doesn't have to follow the same rules as the default.